# How can I interrupt a 'loop' in kdb?

Tags: kdb

numb is a list of numbers:

```
q))input
42 58 74 51 63 23 41 40 43 16 64 29 35 37 30 3  34 33 25 14 4  39 66 49 69 13..

31 41 39 27 9  21 7  25 34 52 60 13 43 71 10 42 19 30 46 50 17 33 44 28 3  62..

15 57 4  55 3  28 14 21 35 29 52 1  50 10 39 70 43 53 46 68 40 27 13 69 20 49..

3  34 11 53 6  5  48 51 39 75 44 32 43 23 30 15 19 62 64 69 38 29 22 70 28 40..

18 30 60 56 12 3  47 46 63 19 59 34 69 65 26 61 50 67 8  71 70 44 39 16 29 45..
```

I want to iterate through each row and calculate the sum of the first 2 and then 3 and then 4 numbers etc. If that sum is greater than 1000 I want to stop the iteration on that particualr row and jump on the next row and do the same thing. This is my code:

```
{[input]
 tot::tot+{[x;y]
   if[1000<sum x;:count x;x,y]
  }/[input;input]
 }each numb
```

My problem here is that after the count of `x` is added to `tot` the `over` keeps going on the same row. How can I exit `over` and jump on the next row?

**UPDATE: (QUESTION STILL OPEN)** I do appreciate all the answers so far but I am not looking for an efficient way to sum the first n numbers. My question is how do I break the `over` and jump on the next line. I would like to achieve the same thing as with those small scripts:

C++

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
if (i = 50) { printf("for loop exited at: %i ", i); break; }
}
```

Python

```
for i in range(100):
  if i == 50:
      print(i);
      break;
```

R

```
for(i in 1:100){
  if(i == 50){
    print(i)
    break
  }
}
```

Comment: your missing the end "]" bracket of you if statement.
not sure what the over is doing here as it going to join input to itself but not return it?

Comment: The idea is to take each row and then go through the numbers 1 by one. For example in the first step the list will be `,42` and then we sum this and see if this is greater than 1000. Then we add the next element and we have `42 58` and we sum this and compare to see if it is greater than 1000. In the real case I have another list and I use and each right to check some condition. My question is if I can break the loop or at least how to ignore the rest of the numbers after the condition was met.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are trying to accomplish.

```
sum {(x & sums y) ? x}[1000] each input
```

It takes a cumulative sum of each row and takes an element wise minimum between that sum and the input limit thereby capping the output at the limit like so:

```
q)(100 & sums 40 43 16 64 29)
40 83 99 100 100
```

It then uses the ? operator to find the first occurance of that limit (i.e the element where this limit was equaled or passed) adding one as it is 0 indexed. In the example the first 100 occurs after 3 elements. You might want add one to include the first element after the limit in the count.

```
q)40 83 99 100 100 ? 100
3
```

And then it sums this count over all rows of the input.

Comment: i think your describing binr instead of find (?). ? will return the max index+1 if it doesnt get an exact match 

```q)40 83 99 101 102 binr 100
```

Comment: hi mark. this is a simplified example of what I need to achieve. my aggregation function is not really a sum. I was more interested in how I can stop the iteration to continue with the same row and jump on the next one when the condition is met

Answer (score 1):

You could use coverage in this case to exit when you fail to satisfy a condition
https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#converge-repeat

The first parameter would be a function that does your check based on the current value of x which will be the next value to be passed in the main function.

For your example ive made a projection using the main input line then increase the indexes of what i am summing each time:

```
q)numb
98 11 42 97 89 80 73 35 4  30
86 33 38 86 26 15 83 71 21 22
23 43 41 80 56 11 22 28 47 57
q){[input] {x+1}/[{100>sum (y+1)#x}[input;];0] }each numb
1 1 2
```

this returns the first index of each where running sum is over 100

However this isn't really an ideal use case of KDB
could instead be done with something like

```
(sums@/:numb) binr\: 100
```

maybe your real example makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

You can use while loops in KDB although all KDB developers are generally too afraid of being openly mocked and laughed at for doing so

```
q){i:0;while[i<>50;i+:1];:"loop exited at ",string i}`
"loop exited at 50"
```

Answer (score 0):

Kdb does have a "stop loop" mechanism but only in the case of a monadic function with single seed value

```
/keep squaring until number is no longer less than 1000, starting at 2
q){x*x}/[{x<1000};2]
65536

/keep dealing random numbers under 20 until you get an 18 (seed value 0 is irrelevant)
q){first 1?20}\[18<>;0]
0 19 17 12 15 10 18
```

However this doesn't really fit your use case and as other people have pointed out, this is not how you would/should solve this problem in kdb.